# What is splay, in the context of networking or automated updates?

Tags: networking

Artur Bergman complained in his Velocity NYC 2013 talk about getting loads of requests at the same time every single hour, with the comment "God I wish people would splay".

I tried searching for it, but due to the largest Swedish Youtube network being called Splay, the term is now completely ungooglable for me.

What does splay mean, in the context of automated updates, cron jobs or networking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Splay" is a term for a very simple concept: deliberate introduction of small random delays in the request timing of a large group of network clients (a so-called [thundering herd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thundering_herd_problem)). This is also sometimes called "jitter", but that term is overloaded in networking to also refer to accidental variation in the timing of received packets due to network congestion, improper queueing, configuration errors, etc.

These delays smooth the distribution of requests in a way that allows the server to handle them over a larger period of time and avoid network congestion.

A related concept is [exponential backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff), though in this case it involves clients waiting a random (and exponentially increasing) amount of time after congestion before a retry.